# How to safely use UniqueEntity (on sites with more than one simultaneous user)

Tags: php, symfony, concurrency, doctrine-orm

Can someone smart can share the design pattern they use to avoid this basic and common concurrency problem in Doctrine\Symfony?

**Scenario:** Each User must have a unique username.

**Failed Solution:**

- Add a [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint to the User entity.
- Follow the [pattern suggested in Symfony's docs](http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/forms.html#handling-form-submissions):  Use the Form component to validate a potential new User.  If it's valid, persist it.

**Why It Fails:** Between validating and persisting the User, the username may be taken by another User. If so, Doctrine throws a UniqueConstraintViolationException when it tries to persist the newest User.

Comment: You could create it early in the process with just the username when it's validated so it can't be taken by someone else?

Comment: @Antony Thompson, thank you for your input.  Minimizing the time between validating and persisting would reduce the frequency.  I'm hopeful it can be eliminated.

Comment: What i mean is persisting it could be part of the validation, so if Doctrine throws a UniqueConstraintViolationException then the username is invalid and you make them choose another one

Comment: Unless you have one of those sites consistently creating thousands of new users per second, the odds of this happening are astonishingly small.  Catch the exception in the exception listener and ask the user to try again.  If you really really really feel you need to protect against this then you can drop down to the doctrine database access connection to insert your user which will allow you to cleanly catch the exception without messing up your entity manager.

Comment: @Cerad, the volume of users is only one factor.  The timing of requests is another.  I'm seeing the exception on a low volume site.  I'm guessing that is because the requests are arriving in batches (due to intermittent network connectivity).  While investigating answers, I notice that you responded to a similar question by suggesting locking.  Locking is the answer here too, I think.  I'm hoping someone can provide an example of how to do it gracefully.

Comment: @Cerad, this is the answer I referred to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644717/concurrent-requests-trying-to-create-the-same-entity-if-not-exists-in-doctrine

Comment: I'm not sure, but why you dont use pessimistic_lock (for innodb/postgres)? somtething like `$entity = $em->find($entityClassName, $id, \Doctrine\DBAL\LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`. The entity will be locked for writing via database itself, until you close transaction (`$em->commit()`).

Comment: @Wizard, we are creating the entity.  Unless I'm mistaken, this only works for entities that exist.

Comment: Just wanted to throw in "transactions". I don't know if that is an option in your case, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what my following answer does:

- It displays errors gracefully to the user if a constraint violation occurs, like if the validator handled it,
- It prevents database updates that are not *"protected"* to break your controller logic (for example with an UPDATE statement or a form submission with *"unprotected"* controllers),
- It is a database-independant solution.

Here is the code, with explanations on comments:

```
<?php

// ...

use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConstraintViolationException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ViolationMapper\ViolationMapper;

// ...

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $task = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);

        try {
            $em->flush();

            // Everything went well, do whatever you're supposed to.
            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException $e) {
            // Reopen the entity manager so the validator can do jobs
            // that needs to be performed with the database (in example:
            // unique constraint checks)
            $em = $em->create($em->getConnection(), $em->getConfiguration());

            // Revalidate the form to see if the validator knows what
            // has thrown this constraint violation exception.
           $violations = $this->get('validator')->validate($form);

            if (empty($violations)) {
                // The validator didn't see anything wrong...
                // It can happens if you have a constraint on your table,
                // but didn't add a similar validation constraint.

                // Add an error at the root of the form.
                $form->add(new FormError('Unexpected error, please retry.'));
            } else {
                // Add errors to the form with the ViolationMapper.
                // The ViolationMapper will links error with its
                // corresponding field on the form.
                // So errors are not displayed at the root of the form,
                // just like if the form was validated natively.
                $violationMapper = new ViolationMapper();

                foreach ($violations as $violation) {
                    $violationMapper->mapViolation($violation, $form);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: "Reopen the entity manager so the validator can do jobs" Don't do this. Once the entity manager is closed, it should not be used again. It may lead to invalid states of entities or entities being persisted again. The entity manager created is a new instance with a new unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is by locking with the symfony [`LockHandler`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/lock_handler.html).

Here is a simple example, using the pattern you are referring in your question:

```
<?php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\LockHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', TextType::class)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // locking here
        $lock = new LockHandler('task_validator.lock');
        $lock->lock();

        // since entity is validated when the form is submitted, you
        // have to call the validator manually
        $validator = $this->get('validator');

        if (empty($validator->validate($task))) {
            $task = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($task);
            $em->flush();

            // lock is released by garbage collector
            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        }

        $form->addError(new FormError('An error occured, please retry'));
        // explicit release here to avoid keeping the Lock too much time.
        $lock->release();

    }

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

NB: This won't work if you run your application on multi hosts, from the documentation:

> The lock handler only works if you're using just one server. If you have several hosts, you must not use this helper.

You could also override the EntityManager to create a new function like `validateAndFlush($entity)` that manage the `LockHandler` and the validation process itself.

Comment: Ideally, the lock would be universal (so likely at the database level).  That way, other lock-ignorant controllers can't break this one.  However, I'll mark this as the correct, bounty-winning answer if a more robust solution is not submitted.

Comment: To catch errors from other *lock-ignorant controllers*, you can add a try-catch on `ConstraintViolationException` during the `flush`. Add an error on the form (if an exception is caught) with `$form->addError(Symfony/Component/Form/FormError('Error occurred, please retry'))`. NB: This is *multi hosts proof* :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not set the unique constraint on database level.
You can also check the [Doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) on how to do this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user",
 *      uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="username_unique", columns={"username"})},
 * )
 */
class User { 

    //...

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", name="username", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $username;

    //...
}
```

Now you have a unique restriction on database level (so the same username can never be inserted in the user table twice).

When you perform your insert operation you will get an exception thrown in case the username already exists (a `UniqueConstraintViolationException`). You can catch the exception and return a valid response to the client where you communicate that this username was already used (was in your database).

Comment: @Kadriles thank you for your comment. I don't really see the problem then, just catch the exception and return a proper response to the client...

Comment: In my point of view, he wants to handle unique constraint violations (or prevent them in every case) to display an error message like the validator ones. This way, clients never see unexpected errors (like a 500 error page). Your answer is one way to do it (try-catch doctrine exceptions).

Comment: @Kadriles is correct.  My main goal is to gracefully notify the user that the username is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you've set a very high bar for yourself.  It's clearly impossible for your persistence layer to see the future.  Thus, it's impossible to support a validator that will guarantee that the insert will succeed (and not throw a UniqueConstraintViolationException) using only your domain entities.  You will need to maintain additional state somewhere.

If you want some incremental improvement, you'll need some way to reserve the username at validation time.  That's easy enough, of course -- you just create a list somewhere to track "in-flight" usernames, and check that list in addition to checking your persistence layer during validation.

Where it gets tricky is designing a sane way to prune that list and release usernames that are submitted for validation, but never used in a successful registration.

That's an implementation detail, and you'll need to consider how long a username-reservation sticks around.

A simple implementation off the top of my head: Maintain a table in your database with (username, session_id, reserved_at) and have some process regularly delete all rows where reserved_at < :datetime.

You'll need to track the session_id, since you're reserving the username for a particular user.  Since the user hasn't created an account yet, the only way to identify them is via their session identifier.

Comment: Is this different than @Vangoso's answer?

Comment: Similar, but not identical.  Vangoso suggests creating an entity class.  I wouldn't consider reserving names for short periods part of the core problem domain, and would therefore eschew creating an entity.  Instead, I'd just use a simple table, or even some cache layer (for instance, if you've already got a redis instance in your stack, you might invent a way to leverage automatic key expiration there)